# Can't make reduce work in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In this Cypher query, I want to sum all the weights over paths in a graph:

```
MATCH p=(n:person)-[r*2..3]->(m:person) 
WHERE n.name = 'alice' and m.name = 'bob'
WITH REDUCE(weights=0, rel IN r : weights + rel.weight) AS weight_sum, p
return n.name, m.name, weight_sum
LIMIT 10
```

In this query, I expect to receive a table with 3 columns: n.name, m.name (identical in all the rows), and weight_sum -- according to the weight sum in the specific path. 
However, I get this error:

```
reduce(...) requires '| expression' (an accumulation expression) (line 3, 
column 6 (offset: 89))
"WITH REDUCE(weights=0, rel IN r : weights + rel.weight) AS weight_sum, p"
```

I obviously miss something trivial. But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
REDUCE(weights=0, rel IN r | weights + rel.weight) AS weight_sum
```

(with a **pipe** instead of a **colon**) as per the documentation in http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/ ?

```
reduce(totalAge = 0, n IN nodes(p)| totalAge + n.age) AS reduction
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: this is embarrassing :-) Thank you